Me gustaria saber como sustituyo el valor "18629" como una variable, he intentado muchas cosas y no funciona, no se si es porque es SQL en AMOS
Me gustaria saber como sustituyo el valor "18629" como una variable, he intentado muchas cosas y no funciona, no se si es porque es SQLen un programa que se llama AMOS
    SELECT
    od_header.orderno,
    od_header.ext_orderno,
    CASE WHEN od_detail.transit_target_date is null THEN od_detail.confirmed_date ELSE od_detail.transit_target_date END AS TTD,
    od_detail.acknowledgement_date,
    (CASE 
        WHEN od_detail.transit_target_date  BETWEEN 18629 AND (18629+90) THEN '1'
        WHEN od_detail.transit_target_date BETWEEN (18629+91) AND (18629+180) THEN '2'
        WHEN od_detail.transit_target_date BETWEEN (18629+181)  AND (18629+270)  THEN '3'
        ELSE '4'
    END) AS Trimestre,
    (od_detail.transit_target_date-od_detail.acknowledgement_date) AS TAT
    
FROM od_detail

LEFT JOIN  od_header ON od_detail.orderno_i=od_header.orderno_i 
        
WHERE 
    od_detail.posno=1 AND
    od_detail.state = 'C' AND 
    od_detail.transit_target_date > 18629 AND
    od_detail.order_type='R' AND
    (od_header.ext_orderno IN ('HPT', 'LPT', 'PT')  OR od_header.ext_orderno LIKE 'ENGI%')

ORDER BY od_detail.transit_target_date


Hola Andrés, presioná [edit] e indicá qué motor de BD utilizas (SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres, etc.)

No se lo que has intentado, pero esto es lo que se me viene a la cabeza
DECLARE @valor INT = 18629

SELECT
od_header.orderno,
od_header.ext_orderno,
CASE WHEN od_detail.transit_target_date is null THEN od_detail.confirmed_date ELSE od_detail.transit_target_date END AS TTD,
od_detail.acknowledgement_date,
(CASE 
    WHEN od_detail.transit_target_date  BETWEEN @valor AND (@valor+90) THEN '1'
    WHEN od_detail.transit_target_date BETWEEN (@valor+91) AND (@valor+180) THEN '2'
    WHEN od_detail.transit_target_date BETWEEN (@valor+181)  AND (@valor+270)  THEN '3'
    ELSE '4'
END) AS Trimestre,
(od_detail.transit_target_date-od_detail.acknowledgement_date) AS TAT

... resto del codigo

Hola Suso, te falto un ; al final de la primer línea.

Hola buenas, me salta cuando lo intento que no puedo poner nada antes del SELECT, y entonces no se dónde declarar la variable.

Tambien puedes hacer un procedimiento almacenado que contenga el codigo y luego donde tenias la consulta ejecutar el proc alm
